# Issue with ng-map (googlemaps) and usergrid backend

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ng-map, usergrid

I'm developing a website (matchbus.tours) which uses :

- Usergrid
- ng-map and googlemaps to display a map with markers
- angularJS
- angular-route

since the last update of googlemaps in april 2018 im having the issue, that the site doesn't load the ng-map anymore.

the console gives the following error:

```
map.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: g is not a function
    at Object.ju.f (map.js:86)
    at Array.<anonymous> (js?key=APIKEY…libraries=places:86)
    at js?key= APIKEY…ibraries=places:131
    at Object.<anonymous> (js?key= APIKEY…libraries=places:60)
    at js?key= APIKEY…ibraries=places:131
    at js?key= APIKEY…libraries=places:60
    at js?key= APIKEY…ibraries=places:131
    at Od (js?key= APIKEY…libraries=places:62)
    at Nd.xa (js?key= APIKEY…ibraries=places:131)
    at common.js:1
ju.f    @   map.js:86
(anonymous) @   js?key= APIKEY…libraries=places:86
(anonymous) @   js?key= APIKEY…ibraries=places:131
(anonymous) @   js?key= APIKEY…libraries=places:60
(anonymous) @   js?key= APIKEY…ibraries=places:131
(anonymous) @   js?key= APIKEY…libraries=places:60
(anonymous) @   js?key= APIKEY…ibraries=places:131
Od  @   js?key= APIKEY…libraries=places:62
Nd.xa   @   js?key= APIKEY…ibraries=places:131
(anonymous) @   common.js:1
```

I don't understand the problem. I know, that removing the usergrid.js (https://github.com/apache/usergrid-javascript) include, resolves the issue but i need usergrid.

Thanks for helping me.